# Pasar valor por constructor de PagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragment

Tengo varias activitys que llaman a un mismo PagerAdapter para tener un layout deslizable en cada una de las actividades que la llamo. Mi intención es la de pasar un parámetro a demás de los que ya le paso. He añadido un elemento de tipo int al constructor y el Android Studio no me detecta ningún fallo, pero ala hora de recibir el valor tiene el mismo valor que cuando lo inicialize a 0. ¿que podría estar mal?

Actividad:

```
MyFragmentPagerAdapter pagerAdapter;

pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    // Create an adapter with the fragments we show on the ViewPager
    MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager(), 1);
    adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.backgroundPager), 0, "Saldo a invertir: ", 1));
    adapter.addFragment(ScreenSlidePageFragment.newInstance(getResources()
            .getColor(R.color.backgroundPager), 1, "Valores a comprar: ", 1));
    pager.setAdapter(adapter);
```

MyFragmentPagerAdapter:

```
public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

// List of fragments which are going to set in the view pager widget
List<Fragment> fragments;
int id_valor;

/**
 * Constructor
 *
 * @param fm interface for interacting with Fragment objects inside of an
 *           Activity
 */
public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int id_valor) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    this.id_valor = id_valor;
}

/**
 * Add a new fragment in the list.
 *
 * @param fragment a new fragment
 */
public void addFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    this.fragments.add(fragment);
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
    return this.fragments.get(arg0);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}

public int getId_valor() {
    return id_valor;
}

public void setId_valor(int id_valor) {
    this.id_valor = id_valor;
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    return "Página " + (position + 1);
}
}
```

ScreenSlidePageFragment.java:

```
public class ScreenSlidePageFragment extends Fragment {

/**
 * Key to insert the background color into the mapping of a Bundle.
 */
private static final String BACKGROUND_COLOR = "color";

/**
 * Key to insert the index page into the mapping of a Bundle.
 */
private static final String INDEX = "index";

/**
 * Key to insert the text into the mapping of a Bundle.
 */
private static final String TEXTO = "index";

ViewPager pagerActual = null;

EditText edtxt;

private int color;
private String textoSta;
private int id_valor;

Saldo saldoObj;
OperacionesBaseDatos opera;
Float precioIntroducido;

/**
 * Instancia un nuevo fragment con un background color, el indice de la pagina y un texto
 *
 * @param color background color
 * @param index index page
 * @param texto texto de tipo de cotizacion
 * @return a new page
 */
public static ScreenSlidePageFragment newInstance(int color, int index, String texto, int id_estado) {

    // Instantiate a new fragment
    ScreenSlidePageFragment fragment = new ScreenSlidePageFragment();

    // Save the parameters
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(BACKGROUND_COLOR, color);
    bundle.putInt(INDEX, index);
    bundle.putString(TEXTO, texto);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragment.setRetainInstance(true);

    return fragment;

}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    // Carga los parametros con los que se sobrecargo cuando la precarga inicial del fragment se completa
    this.color = (getArguments() != null) ? getArguments().getInt(
            BACKGROUND_COLOR) : Color.DKGRAY;

    this.textoSta = (getArguments() != null) ? getArguments().getString(TEXTO)
            : "";

    this.id_valor = (getArguments() != null) ? getArguments().getInt("id_valor") : 0;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.fragment_screen_slide_page, container, false);

    // Establece el texto del TextView con el que se sobrecargo
    TextView tvIndex = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tvIndex);
    tvIndex.setText(textoSta);

    // Establece el color de fondo con el que se sobrecargo
    rootView.setBackgroundColor(color);

    edtxt = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.valores);

    //Funcion de escucha del Button
    Button btnTick = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.buttonInvertirTick);
    btnTick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            cambioCompraValores();
            insertarHistoricoCompraValores();
            cambioSaldo();

        }
    });
return rootView;
}
```

Dentro de ScreenSlidePageFragment.java tengo un metodo en el que llamo al valor id_valor pero me lo carga a zero.

```
int cantidadIntroducido = id_valor;
System.out.println("ESTAS EN:     "+id_valor);
```

Comment: Qué quieres hacer ? No logro entender

Comment: tengo un screen slide donde le sobrecargo con unos valores, mi intención es la de añadir un parámetro mas al constructor y poder tarta la información del parámetro que le añado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acá veo que tratás de sacar el valor del bundle, defaultiando a cero:

```
this.id_valor = (getArguments() != null) ? getArguments().getInt("id_valor") : 0;
```

Pero al cargar el bundle, solo veo que se cargan los Keys color e index:

```
BACKGROUND_COLOR = "color";

INDEX = "index";

TEXTO = "index";

 // Save the parameters
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putInt(BACKGROUND_COLOR, color);
    bundle.putInt(INDEX, index);
    bundle.putString(TEXTO, texto);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
    fragment.setRetainInstance(true);
```

De hecho index está dos veces, por ahí tenés un error por este lado.

Comment: me falto cargar el parametro en el bundle, gracias ;D